# Making comparisons in a HTTPS GET request in node js

Tags: node.js, https, get

```
const https = require("https");
const opts = {
    hostname: "nvdbapiles-v3.atlas.vegvesen.no",
    port: 443,
    path: "/vegobjekter/60.json?egenskap=egenskap(10278)>=2018",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "user-agent": "Testagent",
        "Accept": "application/vnd.vegvesen.nvdb-v3-rev1+json"
    }
};


let dataString = "";
const req = https.request(opts, async res => {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding("utf-8");
    res.on("data", data => {
        dataString += data;
    });

    res.on("close", async () => {
        console.log(dataString);
    });
});
```

I want to get all bridges built after 2018 from a database. This works in browser but breaks because of the ">" when making a GET request. It returns HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [&#47;vegobjekter&#47;60.json?egenskap=egenskap(10278)&gt;=2018]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

What is the correct way of making comparisons in a GET request?

Using node version 14.13.0

Comment: this entirely depends on what the API endpoint supports.  This is not something you can just assume works.  Unless `/vegobjekter/60.json?egenskap=egenskap(10278)>=2018` documents that you can use those kinds of expressions in their request likely means you can't.  You probably have to pull all the data down and filter it some other way.

Comment: this is not a question of comparison it's a matter of acceptable characters/encoding in the request itself (your path param)

Comment: It's directly from the documentation (https://nvdbapiles-v3.atlas.vegvesen.no/dokumentasjon/#avansertefilter), and it works just fine in browser (https://nvdbapiles-v3.atlas.vegvesen.no/vegobjekter/60.json?egenskap=%22egenskap(10278)%3E=2018%22) which is the main point of confusion for me

Comment: Figured it out! The browser automatically changes > to %3e so that's why it was working there. Changing that in the code fixed it.